# Only a column name can be used for the key in a dtype mappings argument

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I've successfully brought in one table using dask read_sql_table from a oracle database. However, when I try to bring in another table I get this error **KeyError: 'Only a column name can be used for the key in a dtype mappings argument.'**

I've checked my connection string and schema and all of that is fine. I know the table name exists and the column i'm trying to use as an index is a primary key on the table in the oracle database.

Can someone please explain why this error occurs when the column name clearly exists?

I know I can use Pandas chunk, but would rather use dask in this scenario.

below is how i'm connecting to the oracle database and the last bit of the error message

```
host='*******'
port='*****'
sid='****'
user='******'
password='*****'

con_string = 'oracle://' + user + ':' + password + '@' + host + ':' + port + '/' + sid 
engine = create_engine(con_string)

df =ddf.read_sql_table('table_name', uri=con_string, index_col='id', npartitions=None, schema='*****')
```

> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py
>   in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, **kwargs)    5855
>   if col_name not in self:    5856                     raise KeyError(
>   -> 5857                         "Only a column name can be used for the "    5858                         "key in a dtype mappings
>   argument."    5859                     )
>
> KeyError: 'Only a column name can be used for the key in a dtype
>   mappings argument.'

Today for another table I added all the column names in ddf.read_sql_table and the query worked. But for another table I tried to do the same thing by listing all the column names and I got the KeyError above.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: This is the read_sql_table calling from its original documentaction: read_sql_table(table_name, con, schema=None, index_col=None, coerce_float=True, parse_dates=None, columns=None, chunksize=None). I believe schema is not necessary, you are already informing that as 'user' in your conn string.

Comment: Thanks powerPixie, I took the schema out but then got the error of the table doesn't exists. I believe that I need to specify the schema because the oracle database has several other schemas. But when I add the schema again I got the error I mentioned in my original post. As far as I know the user that has been created is so I can just read the database. Cheers.

Answer (score 19):

This error generally occurs when there is a mismatch in the column name or there exists a column in the dtype mapping which is not present in the table.

Comment: any idea how to fix when this occurs?

Comment: @RayBell maybe, skipping from the mapping the columns that you no longer need?

Answer (score 0):

The `index_col` is not one of the columns (as it is the index of the dataframe). To fix your issue you'd have to provide the `columns` arg to `read_sql_table` and provide a list of all the columns except the `index_col`.

E.g. in your case, let's say your table has columns id, foo and bar: `df = ddf.read_sql_table('table_name', uri=con_string, index_col='id', npartitions=None, schema='*****', columns=['foo', 'bar'])`