# How to fix a Dask memory error for database table with over a 100 million rows

Tags: python, memory, dask

I'm connecting to a Oracle database with dask.dataframe.read_sql_table to try and bring across some larger tables, some with over 100 million rows and then write them to a s3 Bucket in parquet format. However, I keep running into memory errors even if I try and specify the number of partitions Dask recommends. I've read a bit about dask.distributed but not sure how to use it with dask.dataframe.read_sql_table. I also seem to be running into a KeyError a lot as well. Please follow the link for more information.

[Only a column name can be used for the key in a dtype mappings argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58795861/only-a-column-name-can-be-used-for-the-key-in-a-dtype-mappings-argument)

If anyone has any ideas of how to use dask.dataframe.read_sql_table for reading 100 million row tables it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle using read_sql_table followed by a to_parquet call should be fine.

Without additional information, like a minimal reproducible example, it's not clear how else we can help.  Good luck!